# .htaccess, DNS & linkstructure

Tags: .htaccess, dns, alias

what I'm trying to achieve is forwarding a domain to a subdirectory of my web server.
I need to have several 3rd party domains pointing to the same content whit preserving the link structure.

So no matter if I type in `example.com/page1` or `example.nl/page1` or `example.eu/example1` there should be always the same content.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: sure i tried a "normal" forwarding but obviously the domain gonna be replaced in the address bar. 

Now i have been advised that i will  need a domain pointer / Alias and a DNS A record to achieve that but i´m getting a bit confused here. 

I have the main domain / content on provider 1 and the domains on provider 2.

any ideas how i should proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to server different content under the different domains, assuming you have a directory structure where each domain is a directory under DocumentRoot, you could use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\.com|\.eu|\.nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,PT,NS]
```

Otherwise, just pointing DocumentRoot for all domains at the same DocumentRoot will suffice, albeit with SEO risks.

Comment: hey user2182349 thanks for the fast replay! 

Now this looks good but my main issue is how to setup up. 

I have to make all domains except of the maindomain.com aliases of the the main domain right? 
So i give them all a DNS Record A entry whit only one entry pointing to the main domain server correct?

Than i will have to add your -htaccess?

Comment: Yes, give them all A records and make them ServerAliases

Comment: ok brilliant thanks! 

Now only thing issue which complicate things.
I have the website in a sub folder so the A Record can only take IP addresses right? 

What is best practice to get the domains correctly pointed to the subdirectory? 
I´m using shared hosting so i can not access  Apache config files.

Comment: If you're using shared hosting, there's probably a control panel (cPanel? Plesk?) which will allow you to manage the subdomains and you won't need any rewrite rules.  If you are point the DNS right at the server, the configuration above should serve the subdomain files out of directories with the same name.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still just don´t get it :/ 
my website is under www.maindomain.xz/folder now i pointet the www.otherdomains.something  via DNS Record A To the IP of www.maindomain.xy Now of cause if I visit www.otherdomains.something i end up on www.maindomain.xz root directory. But i need to end up on the /folder and in the best case skip /folder in the address bar. 
So www.maindomain.xz/folder/page1 is the same as www.otherdomains.something/page1
Any ideas what i can do? By the way my hoster is using plesk and the domain provider cpanel

Comment: Ah - sorry about the subdomain mention - the rules in the answer should work as you want them to in an .htaccess file to do what you want if you point all the domains at the server and use the same document root with folders/directories for each domain.  I tested them locally.

Comment: great so i´m on the right track. just to sum it up. 

1. Point www.otherdomains.something via DNS to  www.maindomain.xz
2. use 'RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (\.com|\.eu|\.nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,PT,NS]' to redirect www.otherdomains.something to the right folder? is that correct?

Comment: ok great, will try that today, but what i do not understand where is in your code the the command to point to the correct directory?

Comment: This configuration accepts all the requests, for all the domains, in document root of example.com.  It then rewrites the requests to serve the content from the appropriate subdirectory.